# How we can check the file names using condition

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

On my logic app 6 parallel actions will be there each action will maintain different paths on that path year month dates will be there so we did not hardcoded it. Out of 6 parallel actions 2 of the parallel actions will excecute daily so I want check those two files names so how can I apply the condition action on it

Answer (score 0):

To check file name of the uploaded file, you can use conditions like switch.

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are the steps I followed,

- Created a logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- In switch, given file path to check the condition. There are six cases in switch condition.
- In each case, added flow as shown below,
  [image]
- From the Get file properties action, getting the file name and using it in compose action.
  [image]
- Ran the logic app and able to get uploaded file name based on given condition,
  [image]
- Uploaded file in formulas folder and the name of the file is sample3.
- In this way, you can check file path and get file names based on your flow.

Comment: Thank you vijaya on get file properties what details can I filed can you give me those deatils

Comment: @james you need to take site address, documents (Library name) and id (id of SharePoint trigger) in get file properties action. Refer this document for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/connectors/sharepoint/#get-file-properties

Comment: On id place i was given as my SharePoint path which is in expression

Comment: try with id of previous SharePoint trigger.

Comment: Yes in id place i was given as SharePoint id which is populated i n below dynamic content

Comment: @james add images of what you tried then only we can sort it out